# how do I build with scalac using Leon's library?

Tags: scala, scalac, leon

I am trying to compile my Leon code using scalac directly. Unfortunately, I was not able to properly build the Leon library on which the code depends.

For instance, I have run

```
scalac $(find ~/my-path/leon/library/ -name "*.scala" | xargs) Queue.scala
```

But this actually returns errors:

```
.../leon/library/collection/List.scala:81: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.size.$eq$eq(if (i.$less$eq(0))
  BigInt(0)
else
  if (i.$greater$eq(this.size))
    this.size
  else
    i))
  }} ensuring { _.size == (
                ^
```

What should be passed to scalac to avoid those errors in the library and ultimately compile my own source file?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a type error (or type inference error), rather than a missing library problem. What happens if you explicitly type the parameter of the `ensuring` closure? I.e. `ensuring { (x : Queue) => x.size == ...`.

Comment: See answer below: note that this is from the Leon library, not my code.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I suspect that the attempt here was to execute Leon programs, if so, there is a new option called `--eval` which will evaluate all ground functions (you can filter it further through `--functions` as usual). This should prevent issues with skeleton implementations being non-executable.

About the compilation issue: it should now be fixed in https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon/commit/3d73c6447916516d0ad56806fe0febf7b30a71ad

This was due to type-inference not being able to track types from the declared return type, through the untyped `ensuring`, to the body of the function. This causes `Nil()` to be imprecisely typed in the body, which in turn causes the type-less closure to be rejected.

Why did this work within Leon? Leon inserts a phase in the Scala compiler pipeline before type-checking to inject hints that make this inference possible (and convenient), since the pattern

```
def foo(a: A): B = { a match {
   case ..
   case ..
}} ensuring { .. }
```

is so frequent in Leon programs.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, writing something like:

```
def take(i: BigInt): List[T] = { val res: List[T] = (this, i) match {
    case (Nil(), _) => Nil()
    case (Cons(h, t), i) =>
      if (i <= BigInt(0)) {
        Nil()
      } else {
        Cons(h, t.take(i-1))
      }
  }; res} ensuring { _.size == (
    if      (i <= 0)         BigInt(0)
    else if (i >= this.size) this.size 
    else                     i
  )}
```

...makes it clearly explicit. Scalac was not able to infer the proper parameter type, but this makes the return type of the first block explicit enough. **Note however that this is not a problem using Leon directly, and that is a common syntax used throughout the Leon library, not my code.**

By changing all functions as explained above I was able to compile the Leon Library - but not to run the project using normal scala syntax, since the set implementation in https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon/blob/master/library/lang/Set.scala, which is somehow not used by Leon, is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Following Etienne post:

That works, but we still need to implement sets in https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon/blob/master/library/lang/Set.scala. I did it that way:

```
package leon.lang
import leon.annotation._
import scala.collection.{ immutable => imm }

object Set {
  @library
  def empty[T] = Set[T]()
  protected[Set] def apply[T](elems: imm.Set[T]): Set[T] = Set(elems.toSeq :_*)
}

@ignore
case class Set[T](elems: T*) {
  def +(a: T): Set[T] = Set(elems.toSet + a)
  def ++(a: Set[T]): Set[T] = Set(elems.toSet ++ a.elems.toSet) //Set.trim(elems ++ a.elems) //Set((elems.toSeq ++ a.elems.toSeq).toSet.toSeq :_*)
  def -(a: T): Set[T] = Set(elems.toSet - a)
  def --(a: Set[T]): Set[T] = Set(elems.toSet -- a.elems.toSet)
  def contains(a: T): Boolean = elems.toSet.contains(a)
  def isEmpty: Boolean = this == Set.empty
  def subsetOf(b: Set[T]): Boolean = elems.toSet.forall(e => b.elems.toSet.contains(e))
  def &(a: Set[T]): Set[T] = Set(elems.toSet & a.elems.toSet)
}
```

Unfortunately this cannot be used directly as is in Leon:

```
[ Error  ] 8:31: Scala's Set API is no longer extracted. Make sure you import leon.lang.Set that defines supported Set operations.
         protected[Set] def apply[T](elems: imm.Set[T]): Set[T] = Set(elems.toSeq :_*)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But it works fine for compiling with `scalac` and running with `scala` using:

`scalac $(find ~/my-path/leon/library/ -name "*.scala" | xargs) Queue.scala`

Anyway, if `--eval` does the trick, let's just use it!

Thank you!

Comment: Note that https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon/commit/48c1d6d3a6e67a5f7ddb6cd14085781a1eab5578 now implements skeleton APIs of Set/Map by falling back to Scala sets and maps. This should allow you to compile and execute Leon programs using Scalac.